# Initializing Struct Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm running in some issue while initializing a struct pointer.

```
struct Hook{
    DWORD64 Address;
    vector<BYTE> OriginalBytes;
    vector<BYTE> HookBytes;
    SIZE_T length;
    bool Initialized;
};
Hook *hFuncHook;
void InitializeHookInfo(Hook* hook, DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size){
    hook = new Hook;
    hook->Address = address;
    hook->OriginalBytes = GetAOB(address, size);
    hook->HookBytes.reserve(size);
    hook->length = size;
    hook->Initialized = false;
}
void EndHookInfoInit(Hook* hook, DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size){
    printf("Hook size: %i\n", sizeof(hook)); //returns 8
    hook->HookBytes = GetAOB(address, size);//Crash right there
    hook->Initialized = true;
}

void InitMyHooks(){
     InitializeHookInfo(hFuncHook, mBase + 0xA100FC, 6);
     HookFunction(...);
     EndHookInfoInit(hFuncHook, mBase + 0xA100FC, 6);
}
```

I can't figure out why is this crashing. the InitializeHookInfo part doesn't cause any issue but the EndHookInfoInit just crashes.

Removing the `hook->HookBytes = GetAOB(...);` also causes a crash

Comment: Hint: passing arguments by reference

Comment: What language is this code supposed to be in? It looks like C but you misspelled "malloc"?

Comment: @kfsone `vector<BYTE>` inside a struct definition would be illegal in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer (`T*`) is nothing more complicated than a variable whose value is to be treated as the address in memory of an instance of T unless it contains the value of `nullptr`.

The default behavior for passing variables to C++ functions is pass-by-value.

```
int f(int i) {  // i is local copy of source parameter
    i = 2;  // only modifies local copy
}
```

This is no different when you pass a pointer

```
int f(T* p) {
    p = new T;
}
```

Your code is taking a pointer by value:

```
void InitializeHookInfo(Hook* hook, DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size);
```

so this line of code:

```
InitializeHookInfo(hFuncHook, mBase + 0xA100FC, 6);
```

copies the *value* of hFuncHook into the first argument slot of the function, inside `InitializeHookInfo`

```
void InitializeHookInfo(Hook* hook, DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size) {
    hook = new Hook;
```

this allocates a new Hook and assigns the address *to a local variable*.

You should consider either:

a. return the pointer from your function

```
Hook* InitializeHookInfo(DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size) {
    Hook* hook = new Hook;
    // ...
    return hook;
}
```

b. Take the pointer by address

```
void InitializeHookInfo(Hook** hook, DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size) {
    *hook = new Hook;
```

c. Take the pointer by reference (slightly obnoxious since it's opaque)

```
void InitializeHookInfo(Hook*& hook, DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size) {
    hook = new Hook;  // affects source parameter
```

Or you might rather consider using member functions

```
struct Hook{
    DWORD64 Address { 0 };
    vector<BYTE> OriginalBytes;
    vector<BYTE> HookBytes;
    SIZE_T length { 0 };
    bool Initialized { false };

    Hook() {}

    Hook(DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size)
        : Address { address }
        , OriginalBytes { GetAOB(address, size) }
        , length(size)
    {
        HookBytes.reserve(size);
    }

    void EndInit(DWORD64 address, SIZE_T size)
    {
        std::cout << "Hook size: " << sizeof(*this) << "\n";
        HookBytes = GetAOB(address, size);  // didn't we already do this?
        Initialized = true;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Hook> hFuncHook;

void InitMyHooks()
{
    hFuncHook = std::make_unique<Hook>(mBase + 0xA100FC, 6);
    HookFunction(hFuncHook.get());
    hFuncHook->EndInit(mBase + 0xA100FC, 6);
}
```

Lastly,

```
printf("Hook size: %i\n", sizeof(hook)); //returns 8
```

This is because `hook` is a pointer, you are printing

```
printf("Hook size: %i\n", sizeof(Hook*)); //returns 8
```

you probably wanted

```
printf("Hook size: %i\n", sizeof(*hook)); //returns 8
```